# I have tried to access the variable value of user input variable value in shell scripting

Tags: shell

In shell scripting trying this..

```
echo "please enter the input site value prefixed with \"SITE\""
pwd
read var
SITE1=/u/gsounda/review
SITE2=/u/gsounda/review/one
SITE3=/u/gsounda/review/one/two
SITE4=/u/gsounda/review/one/two/three

cd "$"$var""
pwd
echo "directory has been changed"
```

In this code, i have assigned some site variable value as some directory paths. user will give input as any site value that I have assigned. according to user input automatically current directory should change to that directory. go through this code and try to help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  If you're using `bash`, you could say:

```
cd "${!var}"
```

---

If you're using `ksh`, you'd need to resort to using `eval`:

```
eval "cd \$$var"
```

Comment: No! its showing as "the specified substitution is not valid for this command" :(

Comment: @user3037226 Which shell are you using?  This would work in `bash`.  You would need to invoke your script by saying `bash /path/to/script`.

Comment: @devlnull I am using ksh shell. kindly i request u to explain me little bit clearly.

Comment: @user3037226 See edit above for an alternate if you're using `ksh`.

Comment: Proper use of `eval` requires input sanitization! Anyhow, this would be a lot simpler and more elegant with [`select`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch05_04.htm).